# Points, Pixels and Coordinate System in Cocoa Touch

Tags: cocoa-touch, cocoa, drawing, pixel, point

I'm currently developing an iPhone application. While drawing, I sometimes use coordinates like 35.5|23.5. I know that points aren't the same as pixels. However aren't these coordinates dangerous since the iPhone 3GS has as much pixels as points?

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what you mean by "dangerous". The worst thing that could happen is that you end up with blurry lines that aren't aligned to the pixel grid. If you don't have a non-retina device, you could test in the simulator to see the effect.

Comment: Yeah i just don't want any blurry lines.

Comment: What does sub-pixel mean? 0.5 and so on?